# How to format the header in Tufte Handout?

Tags: formatting, header-footer, tufte

I would like to use the `librecaslon` package with `tufte-handout`. I have encountered a problem in which my headers are printed entirely in lowercase. I believe this occurs because `librecaslon` has no defined smallcaps.

Is there any way I can specify the formatting the header should take, overriding whatever defaults are specified in `tufte-handout`? I don't mind if my header doesn't appear in smallcaps; I just don't want it to appear in all lowercase.

My problem appears to be very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18947/letterspacing-minion-pro-and-tufte-latex-problem-with-running-header), except I'm not using `xetex` so I can't use anything involving `fontspec`.

A minimal example demonstrating my issue is placed below:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\title{This Will Appear in Lowercase in Headers}
\author{Anthony Brice}

\usepackage{librecaslon}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage

foobar

\end{document}
```

Comment: See [tufte-common.def line 1457](https://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/source/browse/tufte-common.def#1457) for where this is defined, and you should be able to redefine the headers (it just uses [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `\smallcaps` to include the desired formatting for headers. Luckily, this command is only used for typesetting the headers, so the impact elsewhere is zero. The lone mandatory argument is the headers' content to typeset, passed internally by the class.

The default definition is

```
\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
```

where `\smallcapsspacing`'s definition is set up later based on the font/engine setup. You can use `\renewcommand` to change `\smallcaps` to whatever is required. As an example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\sffamily #1}

\title{This Will Not Appear in Lowercase in Headers}
\author{Anthony Brice}
\usepackage{librecaslon}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage

foobar   
\end{document}
```

[image]